# LaTeX standard symbol macro

Tags: macros, symbols

I am looking for a list of standard LaTeX macros which are symbols and available without any packages.
Macros like:

```
\LaTeX, \TeX, \slash, \textbackslash, \dots
```

Is there a list for such macros?

Comment: There's a very comprehensive list: the index of source2e.

Comment: The link to TeXnician his document: https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e

Comment: Maybe the first pages of [The Great, Big List of LaTeX Symbols](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf)...